# Static Lib using namespace leads to unresolved external

Tags: c++

I am using VS2013 and I have a static lib project with the following header:

```
#pragma once

namespace StaticLibNamespace
{
    void foo( void );
}
```

Then the function is defined in the cpp as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "StaticLibHeader.h"

using namespace StaticLibNamespace;

void foo( void )
{
    ;
}
```

In my simple console app, I include the reference to StaticLibNameSpaceTest.lib and my main function is the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "..\StaticLibNamespaceTest\StaticLibHeader.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    StaticLibNamespace::foo();

    return 0;
}
```

If I try and compile this I get the following error:
NamespaceTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl StaticLibNamespace::foo(void)" (?foo@StaticLibNamespace@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _wmain

However if I change my static lib cpp file to the following everything is fine:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "StaticLibHeader.h"

void StaticLibNamespace::foo( void )
{
    ;
}
```

I'm obviously not understanding everything going on with "using namespace" can someone please enlighten me?  Thanks!

Comment: The fact you write `using namespace X` doesn't mean that every function you then define must belong to `namespace X`. What if you'd declared a second function `void foo(void)` in your header in the global namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `using namespace` directive changes the lookup rules for symbols when the compiler sees an unqualified name and needs to find what it refers to.

However, in your case, you are defining a *new* function called `foo`. As an unqualified name, this defines a new `foo` in the global namespace (assuming there wasn't already one there). When you qualify the name, you are defining `StaticLibNamespace::foo` as you intend.

A different solution might be:

```
namespace StaticLibNamespace {

void foo( void )
{
    ;
}

} // namespace StaticLibNamespace
```